# how to hide glow effect?

Tags: android, onclick, imageview, glow

Glow effect is working fine.  my doubt is how to hide glow effect? if i click my imageview, that time only i wish to show my glow effect please how to hide and show glow effect while on click.

code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // An added margin to the initial image
        int margin = 24;
        int halfMargin = margin / 2;

        // the glow radius
        int glowRadius = 16;

        // the glow color
        int glowColor = Color.rgb(0, 192, 255);

        // The original image to use
        Bitmap src = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                R.drawable.test);

        // extract the alpha from the source image
        Bitmap alpha = src.extractAlpha();

        // The output bitmap (with the icon + glow)
        Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(src.getWidth() + margin,
                src.getHeight() + margin, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

        // The canvas to paint on the image
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmp);

        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(glowColor);

        // outer glow
        paint.setMaskFilter(new BlurMaskFilter(glowRadius, Blur.OUTER));
        canvas.drawBitmap(alpha, halfMargin, halfMargin, paint);

        // original icon
        canvas.drawBitmap(src, halfMargin, halfMargin, null);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.bmpImg)).setImageBitmap(bmp);

    }
}
```

present screen shot:

[image]

Comment: What is it? R.id.bmpImg . and would you like to say some description about last line?!

Comment: @Mr.Hyde its nothing I have imageview in my layout so i am use that imageview via id. that's all. This is another format you can use this both format 1. ImageView img=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.bmpImg); 2.img.setImageBitmap(bmp);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set onclicklistener and implement this code:

```
.setOnClickListener(clicklistener);


private OnClickListener backListener = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
    // An added margin to the initial image
        int margin = 24;
        int halfMargin = margin / 2;

        // the glow radius
        int glowRadius = 16;

        // the glow color
        int glowColor = Color.rgb(0, 192, 255);

        // The original image to use
        Bitmap src = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                R.drawable.test);

        // extract the alpha from the source image
        Bitmap alpha = src.extractAlpha();

        // The output bitmap (with the icon + glow)
        Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(src.getWidth() + margin,
                src.getHeight() + margin, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

        // The canvas to paint on the image
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmp);

        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(glowColor);

        // outer glow
        paint.setMaskFilter(new BlurMaskFilter(glowRadius, Blur.OUTER));
        canvas.drawBitmap(alpha, halfMargin, halfMargin, paint);

        // original icon
        canvas.drawBitmap(src, halfMargin, halfMargin, null);
}}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can set null for `setMaskFilter()` like this way

```
paint.setMaskFilter(null);
```

and you need just set `paint.setMaskFilter(new BlurMaskFilter(glowRadius, Blur.OUTER));`

for this you need keep paint object for application scope so this paint object can accessing out in another class or activity wherever you want or you can set flag for true then show glow effect and false the flag set nothing (as default)

Comment: thanks and one more doubt how to use onclick event for my image view

Answer (score 0):

An easier way to do this would be to use [`StateListDrawable`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList).

Create two images - one for normal state and one for pressed state (with glow). Use this in the res/drawable/button_drawable.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/image_normal"
        android:state_enabled="true"/>
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/image_pressed"
        android:state_pressed="true"/>
</selector>
```

and use it as the buttom drawable:

```
((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.bmpImg)).setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.button_drawable));
```

Comment: android:drawable="@drawable/image_normal", android:drawable="@drawable/image_pressed" error

Comment: As mentioned, create those images (image_normal.png and image_pressed.png) and add to your drawable folder. Notice the updated XML also.

Comment: The method setImageDrawable(Drawable) in the type ImageView is not applicable for the arguments (int) error line: ((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.bmpImg)).setImageDrawable(R.drawable.button_drawable);

Comment: Please see the updated code: `((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.bmpImg)).setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.button_drawable));`